# Header not working in php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a program that brings an image from the database and displays it inside an image div in my website. The below code was working successfully on my local wamp server but when I moved it to an online server it did not work anymore.

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbConnector.php';
$uID = $_SESSION['loggedUserID'];
$sql = "SELECT photo FROM hostmeuser WHERE userID = '$uID'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if(!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $imgData = "Assets/man.jpg";
}
else
{
    $imgData = $row['photo'];
}
header("content-type: image/jpg");
echo $imgData;
?>
```

I have noticed that all (header) functions are not working on the new server and I have no control over this server so I replaced every:

```
header("Location: example.php")
```

with:

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.replace("example.php");
</script>
<?php
```

it is working fine now on most cases but not this one! 
header("content-type: image/jpg");
Can you suggest any solution for this? or at least do you know how to represent this command in javascript?

Comment: I'd say you should try to fix the cause if the issue, not invest into curing the symptom by finding workarounds. So _why_ don't you calls to `header()` deliver the result you expect?

Comment: What about header() doesn't work? Do you get an error? Does it output the image as though it was ascii? Is there any output to the buffer (browser) before your call to header()?

Comment: When I call header from any page nothing happens ... it's like the command is not there! and the same code works perfectly on my local server

Comment: There is difference between value inside if and else part. Value iside if is string 'Assets/man.jpg' whereas value inside the else part is raw image data. Take care of these! if you want to show if part then you should read the image file from folder and assign the data to variable rather than location

Comment: @Kalkhouri If no errors are shown, can you make sure that PHP error reporting is enabled? `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors','On');`

Comment: I don't know how to enable the error reporting. I wrote these commands in my page. is this what you mean? Nothing happened.